# Windows CMD - open bat from outside including goto

Tags: batch, batch-file

so I have created this utility batch file, shows you all kinds of info, but I wanted it to start on startup of the computer. 
So I have added it to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`
but I want it to go to a spicific menu indicated with `:startup` So I decided I should make a new bat file with something like

`start cmd /k goto startup`

But since there is no `:startup` in that file it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

Insert `goto startup` at the beginning of your batch file.

Or you can insert this line of code:

> `IF /I "%~dp0"=="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Startup" (
>   goto startup
>   )`

at the beginning of your batch file if you want to check if it is in the startup directory first.

Comment: Although this answer is technically correct, I'm pretty sure this is not going to help Sam. I'm pretty sure they want a conditional jump to startup only if the batchfile is in the startup folder.

Comment: @LPChip Updated my answer to rectify this.

Comment: Good update. +1 :)

Comment: Shouldn’t that be %userprofile% in stead of %username% ?

Comment: @Tonny [See here.](https://i.imgur.com/c4PiQnk.png) %Userprofile% is Your username + User Folder. %Username% returns just your username.

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 I know that and hence my comment. Appdata is normally located in the UserProfile, not directly in c:\%username%.  And even better: %APPDATA%  will expand directly to the Roaming folder, including drive-letter (just in case your Windows happens to be on another disk than C:).

Comment: @Tonny You hold a valid point. I've edited my answer based on what you just said.

Comment: This doesnt work, but since `%~dp0` is a parameter, do I first need to define it?

Comment: never mind that question 1 above, but I want to launch it with a shortcut and i want it to read that shortcut's location. How?/

Comment: if `%~dp0` doesn't work (which is strange), try `%CD%`. Answering your second question, you have to change the shortcut's `Start In` parameter in the Properties.

Comment: That works half, if i launch it from the startup folder it gives the wrong location from ‘%~dp0’

Answer (score 1):

You can't jump to a label inside the CMD file from the outside...
Best way is to supply the desired label as a parameter to the CMD file and then use something like

```
if not %1.==. goto %1
```

as the first line in the CMD file.

Comment: Although this is correct, you should also add that in order to supply a parameter to the batch file, one needs to place the batchfile somewhere else, and create a shortcut to the batch file in which the parameter is supplied. The shortcut then is moved to the startup folder itself. You can't supply parameters to a batch file itself, if you place it in the startup folder and just expect it to work.

Comment: @LPChip Of course. But I figured if the OP was smart enough to be able figure out that “ start cmd /k” he would be able to setup the shortcut with parameter.

Comment: Never make assumptions like that, I learned that the hard way. Besides, OP may figure that out, This is still a Q and A site and is found by many others, including those who does not figure that out. Some people may try out your solution, then think: but hey, this is not possible. Downvote! Just saying... :)

Comment: Please explain? Why ‘.==.’?

Comment: @Sam That is just a well-known trick to enable comparing against an empty %1. The syntax doesn't allow for something like IF %1=="" GOTO. So appending a dot after %1 allows you to compare it to a single dot, which amounts to the same thing if %1 is empty.